# Preventing cyclic references on JAXB XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My question is on best (or preferred) practices on preventing cyclic references with `XML` `JAXB` parsing on having bidirectional relationship between `JPA` entities `A` and `B`, as pictured below :

```
                        A
               ________ |__________
              |                    |
              B                    C
      ________|__________
     |                    |
     A                    A
```

I am solving this problem by marking appropriate relationship with  `@XmlTransient`.
Is there any `JAXB` implementation which provides standard resolution on API level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF`

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A{
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private B b;
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B{
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    private String id;

    @XmlIDREF
    private A a;
```

---

[Here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html) an example of the forum of [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan)